# jqGrid JSON WIth SQL JOIN

Tags: jquery, postgresql, jqgrid

I'm having difficulties coming up with a good solution to handle retrieving data from SQL (Postgres 8.4) and displaying it in jqGrid.  The tables of concern are:

1. `meta` ("main" table)...

   ```
   +--------------------------------+
   | id | metaname | metavalue      |
   +--------------------------------+
   |  1 | host     | www.google.com |
   |  2 | ip       | 8.8.8.8        |
   +--------------------------------+
   ```
2. `metauser` (joined to metausedby)...

   ```
   +---------------+
   | id | metauser |
   +---------------+
   |  1 | Tool 1   |
   |  2 | Tool 2   |
   |  3 | Tool 3   |
   +---------------+
   ```
3. `metausedby` (a relational table holding only meta IDs and metauser IDs)...

   ```
   +--------------------------+
   | id | metaid | metauserid |
   +--------------------------+
   |  1 |      1 |          2 |
   |  2 |      2 |          1 |
   |  3 |      2 |          3 |
   +--------------------------+
   ```

The relationship of `meta`:`metausedby`, as you can see in `metausedby`, is one:many.  So my query returns...

```
    +------------------------------------------------------------+
    | id | metaname | metavalue      | metauserid | metausername |
    +------------------------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | host     | www.google.com |          2 | Tool 2       |
    |  2 | ip       | 8.8.8.8        |          1 | Tool 1       |
    |  2 | ip       | 8.8.8.8        |          3 | Tool 3       |
    +------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So what can/should I do to handle building a jqGrid `select` (multi) field to display the multiple possibilities of `metauserid`/`metausername`?  In previous grids I have built the data was almost entirely handled in PHP - a function call to query and then manipulate the JSON to build the jqGrid `select` string (turning multiple records into one where necessary) but I didn't like that approach nor do I think it is very usable with this particular grid.

Maybe my query is less than ideal and it could be handled there or maybe this can easily be handled in Javascript/jQuery (neither of which I am very good at which is why I relied so heavily on PHP data manipulation previously).

The goal is to have a grid something along the lines of...

```
    +---------------------------------------+
    | Meta Name | Meta Value      | Used By |
    +---------------------------------------+
    | host      | www.google.com  | Tool 2  |
    +---------------------------------------+
    | ip        | 8.8.8.8         | Tool 1  |
    |           |                 | Tool 2  |
    |           |                 | Tool 3  |
    +---------------------------------------+
```

Please note in the above sample grid Tool 2 would not actually display; in form edit all tools would display including Tool 2 and tools 1 and 3 would be selected (jqGrid should make this happen automagically if the data is set up properly)

The `Used By` field, when form-editing, needs to be a `select` (multi) field displaying all "tools" from `metauser` and, ideally, would have the appropriate tools selected when editing an existing record.

My current query...

```
WITH paged AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            meta.id as metaid, 
            metaname, 
            metavalue, 
            metauser.id as usedby, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' . $orderBy . ') AS rowNumber 
        FROM meta 
        LEFT JOIN metausedby ON metausedby.metaid = meta.id 
        LEFT JOIN metauser ON metauser.id = metausedby.metauserid
    )

SELECT 
    metaid, 
    metaname, 
    metavalue, 
    usedby 
FROM paged 
WHERE rowNumber BETWEEN ' . $start . ' AND ' . $end . ';';
```

My `usedby` field is defined as follows in jqGrid's `colModel`:

```
    {
        name: 'usedby', 
        index: 'usedby',
        editable: true, 
        editoptions: 
        {
            multiple: true, 
            size: "<?php echo $metaUserCount; ?>", 
            value: "<?php echo $metaUserString; ?>"
        }, 
        edittype: 'select'
    }
```

Of course this displays the `select` field in the edit form (and the appropriate tool is selected for the given record) but due to the JSON (as highlighted in my query's sample output above) I have two separate records for `meta` ID 2... one for Tool 1 and the other for Tool 2.

A factor to consider that may impact the solution is server-side paging that I use with this grid.

This is all probably pretty straightforward for somebody better versed in SQL and jQuery/jqGrid than me so I appreciate your patience and assistance.  One last comment, my grid works with the exception of sorting how to handle this matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to, once I have the data local, loop through it to change the data as I want and manipulate loadonce and the data type to, both dynamically, to accommodate all necessary functionality.